# Multiple confirm boxes Rails link_to

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

Let's say that I have a link on my website that destroys the world when clicked:

```
<%= link_to "Destroy the world", @world, :confirm => 'Are you sure?', :method => :delete %>
```

Obviously, one confirm box isn't enough here. Someone might destroy the world by accident.

What I want to figure out is how to display multiple confirm boxes, one after the other. So for example, instead of only being presented with a box that says "Are you sure?", my users will be presented with "Are you sure?" -> "Are you REALLY sure?" -> "Are you sure that you're sure?", until I finally decide that they're sure enough, and let them destroy the world.

What's the best way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

**The Rails code:**

```ruby
<%= link_to "Destroy the world", @world, :confirm => 'Are you sure?', :method => :delete, :id => "destroy-the-world-id" %>
```

**The Javascript:**

```js
function confirmWorldDestroy() {
    return confirm('Are sure?') &&
           confirm('Are you REALLY sure?') &&
           confirm('Are you REALLY sure you\'re sure?');
}

$(function() {
    $('#destroy-the-world-id').click(function(e) {
        return confirmWorldDestroy();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Pretty easy if you fall back to inline javascript.

```
<%= link_to "Destroy the world", @world, :method => :delete, :onclick => "return confirm('Are you sure?') && confirm('Are you REALLY sure?') && confirm('Are you sure that you\'re sure?')" %>
```

Comment: I tried this earlier today. You get redirected even if you hit cancel.

Comment: I suppose I could use a form and modify a link's onclick to submit() if the user accepted all of the confirm boxes. It sounds a little messy, but I don't really care so long as it gets the job done.

Comment: Hmm. I would have expected the onclick to shortcut the form submit. Are you using Rails 3 with the ujs stuff?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should add a function that you'd call upon submission (:on submit)

It would display all confirmation prompts and return true if all confirmation are received or false otherwise.

If you get a false return, I think the form submission will be cancelled.